# Randomize Two Data Sets

Tags: oracle, postgresql

I am trying to come up with a way to assign two people together from a larger dataset of about 6 people. I was toying around with the random() function in postgres but had no luck. I have access to postgres or oracle whichever may be easier to accomplish this. 
For example if I had 6 names I'd like to take those 6 names and assign them to one another using some sort of randomizing query:

1. Billy
2. Bob
3. Joe
4. Sam
5. John
6. Alex

The output would be something along the lines of:

Orignal Name | Match

1. Billy    | Alex
2. Bob      | Joe
3. Joe      | John
4. Sam      | Bob
5. John     | Billy
6. Alex     | Sam

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In postgres you could generate a row_number() on a random number and then join on that. This is nice and fast, but it could cause people to be buddied up with themselves:

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.name
FROM (SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY random()) as id, name FROM table) t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT row_number() OVER (order by random()) as id, name FROM table) t2 
     ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

---

Here is a method using the cartesian product that results from joining the table to itself. This is not a nice solution if the data is huge as there is an intermediate result set that is (N * (N - 1)) rows, but noone will get matched up with themselves:

```
SELECT name1,
    name2
FROM (
    SELECT t1.NAME name1,
        t2.NAME name2,
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.NAME ORDER BY random()) AS rn
    FROM yourtable t1,
        yourtable t2
    WHERE t1.NAME <> t2.NAME
    ) subquery
WHERE rn = 1;
```

---

Here is a hybrid of the two. Joining the table to itself on a range of randomly generated ids, also specifying that the names don't match. The intermediate result set will have 1-3 randomly chosen names from `t2` for each name in `t1`. Then we just grab one at random. This has an intermediate result set which will ALWAYS be less than (N*3) records which isn't too bad.

**UPDATE**: this will, however, match the same person up multiple times... Leaving it here in case it spawns so good idea for that INNER JOIN that prevents that from happening.

```
WITH randnames AS 
(
    SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY random()) AS id,
        NAME
    FROM yourtable
)
SELECT name1, name2
FROM (
    SELECT t1.NAME name1,
        t2.NAME name2,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.NAME ORDER BY 1) AS rn
    FROM randnames t1
      INNER JOIN randnames t2
        ON t1.NAME <> t2.NAME
            AND t2.id BETWEEN t1.id - 1 AND t1.id + 1
    ) subquery
WHERE rn = 1;
```

I feel like there is probably some prettier way to do this, but the complete lack of answers on this question an hour after it was asked suggests that it's not an easy problem to solve in SQL.

Comment: Thanks JNevill, this seems to work most of the time however there are some instances where some names may be joined together with themselves. Any advice on how to prevent this duplication?

Comment: Oh yeah... I can see that would be a problem. You would have to insure that the row_number() generated for a name isn't generated. I'll noodle on it.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to create some formula that would overwrite the duplicate name with another name but I would run into instances where 1 person would get matched with 2 different people

Comment: Assuming the data isn't yuge, then you can check out the other option I just posted.

Comment: This query is going to be used to randomly assign people to a "Buddy". Currently there are only 6 names I have and your query works great to assign people but some refreshes may assign someone to themselves.

Comment: I took one more stab at this combining the cross-join and random() queries into one. The intermediate result set will be less than (N*3) records which is reasonable for any table size and it will insure that noone gets matched to themselves and everyone has a match.

Comment: This woke me up in the middle of the night thinking about it. It's such a simple problem, but I don't think either of these three get it exactly right. The last is the closest and I think the biggest problem can be solved by doing `AND t2.id BETWEEN t1.id AND t1.id + 1` dropping the `-1` from the way I have it written. This means touhg that in some very rare circumstances the last name in the t1 could be dropped silently from the output (when they are buddied with themselvf) That might be the best bet though from a logic and speed standpoint.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate all the help.